# Trying to install Tailwind on Laravel 8 but getting error on cmd

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, tailwind-css, laravel-mix

I followed the following steps but getting an error on cmd.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel tailwindcss 8
npm install 
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Error in cmd after npm run dev:

[image]

Addition in files are as follows:

`tailwind.config.js`

```
purge: [ 
    './storage/framework/views/*.php', 
    './resources/**/*.blade.php', 
    // './resources/**/*.vue', 
],
```

Comment: addition in files are follows :
1.tailwind.config.js
  purge: [
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    // './resources/**/*.vue',
  ],

Comment: Please share more details, like all error messages in readable form (that means: text), and your attempts to resolve them

Comment: In order to see what the issue is, please post your package.json and your webpack.mix.js.